# ¿Porque me desordena ajax el Json cuando lo recibe?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

El problema es que quiero pasar desde php un json, el cual he ordenado previamente desde la consulta sql usando `order by`, el JSON lo envío con `echo json_encode($arr_JSON)` y cuando lo muestro en el navegador sale de la siguiente manera:

[image: JSON con un key, el cual tiene un array con dos datos]

Sin embargo, cuando recupero el JSON con ajax, ordena automaticamente los keys numericamente de la siguiente manera:

[image: El JSON se ha ordenado por la key]

¿Existe alguna forma de evitar que me ordene numericamente al enviarlo?

El codigo ajax que tengo es el siguiente:

```
function mostrarTareas(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php_funciones/tareas.php",
    data: { variable: 'value' },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        for (const key in data) {
            let linea= "<tr><td>Farmaco: "+data[key][0]+"</td><td> Hora: "+data[key][1]+"</td></tr>";
            $("#tabla_tareas").append(linea);

        }
    }
});
}
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizare otros datos para el ejemplo, ya que tu **JSON** es extenso.

Tu **JSON** original:

```
{"3":"Andy", "1":"Bruce", "4":"Charlie", "2":"David"}
```

El **JSON** después de recibirlo:

```
{"1":"Bruce", "2":"David", "3":"Andy", "4":"Charlie"}
```

Lo que estás enviando es una serie de objetos, así que tu estructura de datos debería reflejar eso idealmente.

Y transfiriéndolo como un **array** puedes mantener el orden. Por lo tanto el aspecto que debería de tener tu **JSON** es:

```
[{"id":"3", "name":"Andy"}, {"id":"1", "name":"Bruce"}, {"id":"4", "name":"Charlie"}, {"id":"2", "name":"David"}]
```

Referencia: [getJSON not maintaining original order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31868232)